# Apply any callback in a custom training loop in TF2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, tensorflow2.0

I am writing a custom CycleGan training loop following [TF's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan?hl=en). I'd like to use several existing callbacks, and prefer not re-writing their logic.

I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438904/applying-callbacks-in-a-custom-training-loop-in-tensorflow-2-0), whose answers unfortunately focused on EarlyStopping, rather than on the broad range of callbacks.

I further found this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/cwkjlz/is_there_a_clean_way_to_use_keras_callbacks_in/), which suggested to call them manually. Several callbacks however work with an internal model object (they call `self.model`, which is the model they are applied on).

How can I simply use the existing callbacks in a custom training loop? I appreciate any code outlines or further recommendations!

Comment: How about official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback)?

Comment: If you prefer using built-in `callbacks` in a custom training loop, then you can't. You have to write the logic by yourself.

Comment: However, I would advise using `.fit` by customizing it - override the `train_step`... In that way, we can use all the convenience functionalities of the fit method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the existing callbacks you have to create the callbacks you want and pass them to callbacks argument while using model.fit().

For example, i want to use the ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=1)
```

Create a callbacks_list

```
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, es]
```

pass the callbacks_list to callbacks argument while training the model.

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),epochs=10,callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/56086d16fe8dcc60f3faa308491e7169) for complete code example. Thank You.